# Quickblox - QMCVDevelopment pod not working anymore

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

As you can see in:

[image: Terminal]

I am not able to install this specific pod.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some more details of your pod file structure

Comment: Do not post text with images please !!!

Answer (score 0):

This pod seems be broken.

You can clone the repo successfully but linting the spec

```
pod spec lint QMCVDevelopment.podspec
```

Gives 2 errors and many warnings.

> - NOTE  | [QMCVDevelopment/Utils,QMCVDevelopment/Views] xcodebuild:  QMCVDevelopment/QMChatViewController/Utils/QMImageLoader/QMImageLoader.m:10:9: fatal error: 'Quickblox/Quickblox.h' file not found
> - ERROR | [QMCVDevelopment/ViewModels,QMCVDevelopment/Sections] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.

You could consider debugging the issue and submitting a PR to the author.

You can also create your own local fix by using a local repo in your pod spec for yourself.

e.g

```
pod 'QMChatViewController', :path => "~/src/somewhere/dontcare/QMChatViewController"
```

If you want to use third-party dependancies, this is the cost (a.k.a "Theres no such thing as a free lunch")

Answer (score 0):

Please try these pod to working chat, audio, video call no need to extra pod required

```
 pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC'
 pod 'QuickBlox'
 pod 'QMChatViewController'
 pod 'QMServices'
```

any query please ask

Answer (score -1):

For Quick Blox Please Use these pods it will work fine
 pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC'
 pod 'QuickBlox'

For More Accurate answer please provide exact functionality which you are looking at.

Comment: I have added these still no luck. I am trying to add "ChatViewController" from "Sample-Swift-Chat" into my own project.. All the pods are there including pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC' pod 'QuickBlox' but still not working...
Getting "'Quickblox/Quickblox.h' file not found"...